# What are the string property names of MQConstants.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY and JMSConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I want to set the MQConstants.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY and JMSConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP in  WAS console > Resources > JMS > Queue connection factories > QueueConnFactoryDEV > Custom properties, does anyone know the property values? Thank you in advance.

1. In IBM MQ classes for Java, set the property MQConstants.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY to true in the properties hashtable passed to the com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager constructor.

   - Is the property value USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY?
2. In IBM MQ classes for JMS, set the property JMSConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP to true, on the appropriate connection factory prior to creating the connection.

   - Is the property value USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP?
3. Globally, set the System Property com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication to a value indicating true, for example, by adding -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=Y to the command line.

   - How to set this in websphere?

**EDIT:**
Instead of

```
cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
```

I want to set

```
cf.setBooleanProperty("USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP", true);
```

since I will be putting it in custom properties.

Comment: The property seems to be boolean, as shown in an example [here](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2015/11/11/specifying-user-name-password-mq-application/).

Comment: @XSurgent, yes, the property values are boolean but I want to get the property names of MQConstants.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY and JMSConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP since I need to set it in custom properties of queue connection factory in websphere.

Answer (score 1):

These constants appear in the [WMQConstants](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/msg/client/wmq/WMQConstants.html) API. Seems to have been a [reorg](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21423244)  in later releases.

However, are you sure you're taking the right approach given that you're accessing WMQ **within** WebSphere Application Server (rather than through a standalone Java program)?

WMQ in particular and JMS providers in general are managed resources within the app server, so along with connection pooling you get a set of server-integrated authentication options like an auth alias.   See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21580097) and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0901_leming/0901_leming.html) and [here](https://share.confex.com/share/124/webprogram/Handout/Session17040/CL_Using_WMQ_With_WAS.pdf) for more reading on authentication and WMQ in the app server in general.